# Add new value to query result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a query using Entity Framework that looks like this:

```
var CompanyDetail = await _dbContext.tablename
                                    .Where(cu => cu.Id == newId)
                                    .Select(cu => cu.Carrir)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It is working fine and returning all details perfectly.

Now I want to add new value to this result set I get:

```
var status = await _documentSettingService.IsValid();
```

This above value is not stored in this current table, so what I want is when this function return data then it should added this above value in that Entity Framework result set.

I have two questions :

1. Is it possible or not, and if yes - how to do that?
2. Is it good in terms of practice ?

Thanks

Comment: Usually you will create a new class (DTO) which will contain all needed fields and copy data there.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want - to status to companydetails or companydetails to status. And I think it would be nice if you show all proprties of both classes - status and company details.

Comment: please in first , convert `var CompanyDetail = await _dbContext.tablename.Where(cu => cu.Id == newId).Select(cu => cu.Carrir).FirstOrDefaultAsync();` To `var CompanyDetail = await _dbContext.tablename.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cu => cu.Id == newId).Select(cu => cu.Carrir);` and then as Serge said : explain what do you want exactly .

Comment: Right now I am getting data from select query and it is coming based on model class, but in that result I want to add new value that status..but I don't want to add any new attribute in model class..without adding in model I want to add status value in query result.

Answer (score 0):

Like Guru Stron said, you should create new class `(DTO)` with `CompanyDetail` and `Status` fields.

If you don't want to create a new class, there are some alternative way

```
(string, bool) result = (CompanyDetail, status);
```

or using `anonymous` type object

```
var result = new { CompanyDetailResult = CompanyDetail, StatusResult = status};
```